# How to walk a C# object hierarchy and create JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, reflection, converters

I am creating a metadata site for our API. It is like swagger implementation. Currently I am facing difficulty with creating a sample JSON representation of our request response objects. These are complex objects that may even contain lists.

Right now I am at the point where via using reflection I am able to find all the request and their corresponding response objects.

Is there a library that can convert a reflection

```
assembly.GetType("FullyQuallifiedObjectName")
```

output to a JSON sample string? My research so far has not been fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing your own inspector class may be too difficult and take much time. You may consider [Microsoft's way to build help pages in WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages). New Mvc4 and Mvc5 projects in VS2013 already contain **complete** help pages in WebApi templates.

(You do not need to implement custom `XmlDocumentationProvider`, just create a new WebApi project in VisualStudio 2013 and you will find completed xml doc provider)

If you use WebApi - it's exactly what you need. If not - modify and reuse already implemented xml doc provider.

Comment: We have pre-existing apis, which are using service stack. ServiceStack's swagger implementation doesn't provide the kind of functionality we need.

Comment: I suggested you to adapt WebApi help page generator to your service. If it seems too difficult you may create sample request/response objects and serialzie them to JSON using JSON.NET library.

Comment: I have tried JSON.NET. It doesn't work with reflection objects.

Comment: Why do you pass "reflection object", what is it? Just create an instance of a class, fill it's properties with sample data and serialize to json. Add reference to the assembly if required...